# email/pic format problem

Tags: email, images, attachments, forwarding, orientation

A client sent me some vertical pics but they show up on my server as horizontal images. I viewed them via the browser -did not use an email client to view them. I forwarded his email to him and he says when he opens it the images are vertical. I don't have a clue.

Comment: are they sent in the email as attachments or links?

Answer (score 1):

If the images are in jpg format, it is possible that your client uses a viewer which rotates images according to orientation field in exif data.